# How do i use Slim Engine in Espresso Framework

Tags: ruby

Ok, seems i'll go with Espresso.
It is really clean and easy.

Are there built-in support for Slim?

Can not find anywhere in docs how to use it.

Trying this:

```
require 'e'
require 'slim'

class Blog < E

  engine :Slim
  # etc.
end
```

and getting a weird error about no `Slim` engine found, though i loaded it.

Comment: Are you using bundler? If so, is `gem 'slim'` included in your Gemfile?

Comment: as you can see, i'm requiring it directly

Comment: That is not the same! Are you using Bundler? I had a similar issue today where I installed a gem manually with `gem install ...` and tried using it directly in a gem that uses bundler that I was working on. Just requiring the other did not suffice, it needed to be in the Gemfile too. Just give it a try if you use bundler. You might not even need to have a `require 'slim'` statement in the source then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that `Espresso` using `Tilt` for rendering.

And `Tilt` has no built-in support for `Slim`.

However, `Slim` does have built-in support for `Tilt` :)

All you have to do is to register a new `Tilt` template:

```
require 'slim'

Tilt::SlimTemplate = Slim::Template
```

That's it. Now you can use it like this:

```
class Blog < E

  engine :Slim
  engine_ext :slim
  # etc.
end
```

Please note `engine_ext :slim` - it will inform `Espresso` about templates extension.

Most likely you'll name your templates like `template-name.slim`